# How to show/hide fields with the Rules module based on the user's language?

Tags: 7, entities, rules, i18n-l10n

I have a multi-language support website.

My question: can I show/hide some fields based on the user's language choice with [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) module?

Answer (score 3):

The [Conditional Fields](http://drupal.org/project/conditional_fields) module might be of help to you.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [Field formatter conditions](https://www.drupal.org/project/ffc) module, and its integration with the [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) module.

Refer to the [video about Field formatter conditions](https://m.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_embedded&v=WDiNu_v06AY) for a demo of what is pretty close to what you're looking for. Especially starting from around 4:50 in the video, you can see the Rules action "Hide a field".

So with that, your question is reduced to something like "*How should my the event and optional conditions for the Rules module look like, related to the user's language choice (to apply the "Hide a field" action)?*". The answer to that question could be another question of course ...

**Note**: the article about [Introducing Field formatter conditions for Drupal](http://realize.be/introducing-field-formatter-conditions-drupal) provides some more background reading about this video also.